# Prevent Calc spreadsheet from recalculating while macro is running

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a macro which inserts values into several cells in a LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet. It is very slow, and what appears to be happening is that after every call to `.Formula=` the entire spreadsheet recalculates formulas before the macro can proceed.

Is there a way to temporarily stop automatic recalculation while a macro is running, then recalculate after the macro completes?

Comment: You are probably looking for [**enableAutomaticCalculation**](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XCalculatable.html#enableAutomaticCalculation) and `calculate()` (or `calculateAll()`). Nevertheless, I would advise you not to rush to use them, but try to understand why the calculation takes a long time - perhaps you have overloaded your spreadsheet with cumbersome calculations that can and should be optimized.

Comment: @JohnSUN Thank you. I'd accept that as an answer if you wanted the internet points.

Comment: Thank you, my friend, but no. Let's be honest - this is not an answer, but only a hint. If you and I would speed up the macro (or formulas) of your spreadsheet many times so that there would be no need to turn off automatic recalculation - this would be the answer that would help many. Since I do not want to recommend "intentionally corrupting Calc" to many users, so this is not a real answer.